# php substr - how to find <br> before starting substr?

Tags: php

I'm using this with success

```
$str = "{source}do_something";
if(substr($str, 0, 8) == "{source}")
```

but what should I do if I've

```
$str = "<br><br>{source}do_something";
```

the goal is to be able of adding blank lines (as many as needed) before firing up my do_something

Thanks

EDIT

ok, so I need to run the function

*menu*;vertical,true

but I also need to have those blank lines before my menu

my string is

```
<br><br><br><div>{source}_menu_;vertical,true{/source}</div>
```

with no line breaks I use

```
if(substr($pos, 0, 8) == "{source}") {
    $campos = substr_replace($description, '', 0, 8);
    $campos = substr($campos, 0, -9);
    $funcao = explode(";", $campos);
    call_user_func_array($funcao[0], array($funcao[1]));
}
```

now I need the same thing but with the line breaks, so the browser actually renders line breaks and then runs the function.

I hope my english is good enough to make this clear...

Thanks

**NEW EDIT with solution**

```
$startTag = "{source}";
$endTag = "{/source}";
$initial_strpos = strpos($str, $startTag);
$final_strpos = strpos($str, $endTag);
if ($initial_strpos !== false) {
    $beforeTag = substr($str, 0, $initial_strpos);
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($beforeTag, ENT_QUOTES);
    $start = $initial_strpos + strlen($startTag);
    $innerText = substr($str, $start, strpos($str, $endTag)-$start);
    $funcao = explode(";", $innerText);
    call_user_func_array(array_shift($funcao), $funcao);
    $aferTag = strpos($str, $final_strpos);
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($aferTag, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

this will print my line breaks and run my function.

Comment: You could compare the string after running  `strip_tags()` on it - if that works for you. It's not entirely clear what your end goal is

Comment: Are you trying to extract string between curly brackets `{` and `}` ?

Comment: exactly, my goal is to run a function whose name is inside {source} like <br><br><br><div>{source}_menu_;vertical,true{/source}</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to check the first 8 characters specifically, then you should remove the `<br>`s from the string before doing the substring:

```
if (substr(str_replace("<br>", "", $str), 0, 8) == "{source}")
```

This won't work if the string is slightly different, i.e. `<br />`. The best way to do this would probably be:

```
if (strpos($str, "{source}") !== false)
```

**EDIT**

How about this? It should get the text between the `{source}{/source}` tags and split them by `;`, then take the first entry as the function name and the second as parameters to the function.

```
$startTag = "{source}";
$endTag = "{/source}";
$strpos = strpos($str, $startTag);
if ($strpos !== false)
{
    $start = $strpos + strlen($startTag);
    $innerText = substr($str, $start, strpos($str, $endTag)-$start);
    list($functionName, $parameters) = explode(";", $innerText);
    call_user_func_array($functionName, explode(",", $parameters));
}
```

Comment: ok, your reply is almost correct, or is correct, but It's missing initial_strpos and final_strpos so we can print whats before, the function and what's after. I'm going to reedit my question to make this accessible to everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

```
$pos = strrpos($str, "{source}");
if ($pos === false) { // note: three equal signs
    // not found...
} else {
    // found
}
```

**EDITED after your new comment:**
You could try something like:

```
$from = 1 + stripos($str, "{");
$to = stripos($str, "}", $from) - 1;
$your_string = substr($str, $from, $end - $from + 1);
```

Naturally you should check that both indexes (`$from` and `$to`) are ok, but this example should give you an idea...

Answer (score 1):

See the manual for strrpos: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

So you can findout the position of br-tag.